# DXA 1.4 Managing page includes

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa-1.4

We are managing the page includes from tag **tri:page** to tag **dxa:region**, as we found in the dxa 1.4 documentation the following recommendation

> to simplify the page model structure and improve the clarity of
>   the View code, starting from version 1.2,  SDL Digital Experience
>   Accelerator 1.2 treats Page Includes as Page Regions.
>
> If you are still using Page Includes, DXA will display a warning
>   message during the compilation of the View code.

However in the same doc there's a section about [page includes](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20DXA-v4&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-5E88B1FC-FA9A-46F0-B7A5-89FCF058DB23&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-5E88B1FC-FA9A-46F0-B7A5-89FCF058DB23.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-5E88B1FC-FA9A-46F0-B7A5-89FCF058DB23) and we are confused about if:

1. In the page template is still necessary to include the list of URLs?
2. For each include page, we are using the page template Include Page (without any metadata schema) associating the necessary component presentations, is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include Pages are still managed in the same way in CM (so the answer to both questions is "yes"). The only difference is in how they are represented in the DXA Page Model in the Web Application.